# Why saving in xlsx is not working, but in xls is?

Tags: vba, excel

I made a code to help me save some files quickly in a folder optimasing an online exemple. When i save the file in xls format, everything looks normal, but when i do it in xlsx and try to open the saved file, an erro appears telling me that the format is corrupted.

All files where in xls in beginning

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()

'PURPOSE: To loop through all Excel files in a user specified folder and perform a set task on them
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

 'security biass
If Worksheets("atualizador").Range("H6") <> "x" Or Worksheets("atualizador").Range("H7") <> "x" Then
    Exit Sub
End If

  'start folder
  myPath = "C:\Users\anna.costa\Downloads\Dados\"


'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
  myExtension = "*.xls"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

    'copy Worksheet's and rename
      If Right(myFile, 5) <> ")" Then
        Select Case Left(myFile, 1)
            Case "V"
            wb.SaveAs ("C:\Users\anna.costa\Desktop\Dados_FIPE\ANBIMA\VNA\" & setnameVNA(myFile) & ".xlsx")
            wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
            Case "m"
            wb.SaveCopyAs ("C:\Users\anna.costa\Desktop\Dados_FIPE\ANBIMA\TÍTULO_PÚBLICO\" & setnameTP(myFile) & ".xls")
            wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
            Case "C"
            wb.SaveCopyAs ("C:\Users\anna.costa\Desktop\Dados_FIPE\ANBIMA\ETTJ\" & setnameETTJ(myFile) & ".xlsx")
            wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        End Select
      End If

    'Get next file name
      myFile = Dir
  Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
  MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/662460-visual-basic-applications-savecopyas-how-can-i-save-copy-xlsx.html  I don't think you can use SaveCopyAs to save a copy in a different format, so if you have an xls the copy can only be xls.  You can't change the format just by changing the extension to xlsx.

Comment: You are opening xls files from VBA...and you want to save a xls file to xslx without any convertion.....You can try something like: `wb.SaveAs "C:\Users\anna.costa\Desktop\Dados_FIPE\ANBIMA\ETTJ\" & setnameETTJ(myFile) & ".xlsx", 
FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, AccessMode:=xlExclusive, ConflictResolution:=Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges
wb.Close SaveChanges:=False`

Comment: @TimWilliams I tryed in V case, but SaveAs also didin't work

Comment: @Hackerman it worked perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: I am glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to open an `xls` file and save it as an `xlsx` file, without any conversion. To properly convert the file to `xlsx` you need to include the right `FileFormat`:

```
 wb.SaveAs "C:\Users\anna.costa\Desktop\Dados_FIPE\ANBIMA\ETTJ\" & setnameETTJ(myFile) & ".xlsx", _
 FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, AccessMode:=xlExclusive, ConflictResolution:=Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges 
 wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar situation, what I did was this

```
Set WBDesiredToConvert = ThisWorkbook
WBDesiredToConvert.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "MacroEnabled", 52
```